# I think there is a Jinn with me

Tags: jinn

Assalamu alaikum. I am from Bangladesh an I'm a girl aged 29. Since 2019, I think there is a Jinn with me. During sleep, I sometimes can't move and feels like someone has grabbed me so tight from back or above. I feel like someone is having intercourse with me. One already said there is something with me. If it really is, then how to detach him form me? Is it even possible to have a permanent solution???